# Multiple disks in crypttab. Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: encryption, luks

I have added the contents of the `crypttab` file manually. This is their form:

```
Name1 UUID=******** none luks
Name2 UUID=******** none luks
```

During startup, the system asks for the passphrase to unlock the first one normally but it does not ask anything about the second one. Strangely, probably because I have used the same passphrase for both partitions, it unlocks the second one too successfully.

Is this a normal operation? Does it actually attempt to unlock the second partition using the passphrase I have typed for the first one? What would it do if I had used different passphrases for each partition?

Thank you.

Comment: Try reading this, it should answer your questions too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392286

Comment: @Clover, according to what I've read, `luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` has to be used in the `crypttab` so that the script is enabled. Since I haven't used this option, do we assume that the script is enabled by default on Ubuntu?

Comment: it seems so, looking at the contents of file `/usr/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl` I see it is used "systemd-ask-password" and running `systemctl status systemd-ask-password-console.service`I see it is loaded.

Comment: @Clover, thank you. If you copy your comment to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer explain how a single passphrase can unlock multiple encrypted disks:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392286

**In addition**

The current version of *ubuntu seems to automatically load the mentioned script without being specified.

Looking at the contents of the `/usr/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl` file you see that "systemd-ask-password" is used.

By running the command `systemctl status systemd-ask-password-console.service` you can check if the service is actually loaded.

Comment: @Stormlord And the script cannot be disabled?